# Cakephp 3 renew session with every request

Tags: session, cakephp-3.0

I'm working with the Auth component in Cake and I'm trying to let the session be renewed with every request.

As per the documentation:

```
'ini' => [
        // Invalidate the cookie after 30 minutes without visiting
        // any page on the site.
        'session.cookie_lifetime' => 1800
    ]
```

Even by using this the user gets signed out every 30 minutes, regardless of any requests made.

In addition to this I've added:

```
'timeout' => 30
```

This doesn't change the behavior.

So what I'm trying to achieve is the following:

When the user signs in create a session that stays valid for 30 minutes, with every request refresh the session. So that only if the user is actually inactive for more than 30 minutes (no page loads, no Ajax calls) the user gets signed out.

Comment: I think you are supposed to use seconds for session timeout, https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#session-configuration

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The Cake documentation states: Session.timeout - The number of minutes before CakePHP’s session handler expires the session.

Comment: You're right, but I also see this in their documentation 'session.cookie_lifetime' => 1800

Comment: Indeed, and that's in minutes. Just to make it easy I suppose...

Answer (score 0):

Mine seems to work just fine with a timeout of 15 minutes. Here's what I have in my AppController

```
public function initialize() 
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'loginAction' => '/admin/login',
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'finder' => 'auth',
                'passwordHasher' => [
                    'className' => 'Fallback',
                    'hashers' => [
                        'Default',
                        'Legacy'
                    ]
                ],
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'email_address', 
                    'password' => 'password',
                ],
                'userModel' => 'User',
            ],
        ],
        'storage' => 'Session'
    ]);
}
```

In config/app.php

```
'Session' => [
    'defaults' => 'cache',
    'timeout' => 15,
    'handler' => [
        'config' => 'session'
    ]
],
```

Here is the cache config for Session:

```
'Cache' => [
    'session' => [
        'className' => 'Redis',
        'duration' => '+90 days',
        'path' => CACHE,
        'url' => env('CACHE_DEFAULT_URL', null),
    ],
```

Granted I am using Redis for session storage and have specialized Auth a bit for our use-case. If all that all seems similar to what you have configured then maybe its your php.ini settings? I'm running CakePHP 3.5 with PHP 7.0 FPM on Ubuntu 18 + Apache. Fairly certain I am using the default settings, but maybe I've adjusted those.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I prefer not to use Redis. If no other solution is found I'll look into this. Thanks again!